# Cloning Windows 2003 Server to new hard drive results in failure

Tags: windows-server-2003, hard-drive, clone

Scenario:

Old hdd is a Seagate 320gb SATA drive

New hdd is a WD 320gb SATA drive

Created an exact clone and replaced old hdd with new hdd.

Boot up with new hdd, it gets into Windows 2003 server environment but things look weird. Lots of system event failures in the event viewer log. System is barely unusable, critical services are all down.

Boot up with old hdd, everything is fine.

QUESTION: Is it possible to do a simple clone of a Windows 2003 server system? All I'm changing is the hard drive, everything else stays the same (old CPU/old mobo/etc..)

Comment: How is the cloning done, what software and settings?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it should work fine if it's an accurate clone and there are no errors preventing the cloning to succeed.